# King Of the Hill playing a Copyrighted game

Tags: discussion, king-of-the-hill

## Copyrighted King of The Hill Games

Some Game X is created and copyrighted by corporation Y. Can I post a king of the hill challenge about Game X, or some derivitave of X? This issue came up [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9922/46918) as well as my [related post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9653/46918). Does this relevant [copyright info](http://www.copyright.gov/fls/fl108.pdf) apply?

---

## Some Relevant Questions

If it is ok, should I cite corporation Y?

Should we use more generic terms? (Frisbee -> Disc)

Comment: [Related](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/how-closely-can-a-game-legally-resemble-another)

Comment: @PeterTaylor whoops should have seen that. Voted to close my own question.